# Is there a way to control more specifically the drag event of konva objects?

Tags: konvajs, konva

For example, by setting `stage.draggable(true)`
we can make a stage draggable.

By default, it is a continuous motion, meaning that every time when the mouse exerts dragging on a stage, the drag event is invoked. This causes lagging in my application, probably because of the large amounts of shapes that need to be redrawn after each drag event.

So, is there a way to control the timing of invoking drag event? Or maybe can I set a small time gap between each drag event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in `Konva` you can't control timing of invoking drag event.

`Konva` is updating positions and firing `dragmove` event on every `mousemove/touchmove` event.

**But it doesn't draw immediately.** It draws as soon as possible with [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame).

If you want to have full control over dragging you can implement it manually.
Like (1) listen to `mousedown/touchstart` event, (2) move node on `mousemove/touchmove` and (3) stop dragging on `mouseup/touchend`.

In the best case, you need to find ways to optimizing drawing. Usually caching improve performance of drawing a lot. You can cache on `dragstart` and clear cache on `dragend`.

For more performance tips take a look here: https://konvajs.org/docs/performance/All_Performance_Tips.html

Comment: This helps.Thanks a lot.